# Does a limit exist for the fraction of $p\alpha_i$?

Tags: diophantine-approximation

With $p$ an integer and $\alpha_i$ a real number, does $\{p\alpha_i\}\leq\epsilon$ hold for some predefined $\epsilon$, maybe depending on the number of $\alpha_i$ values? I looked at the simultaneous version of the Dirichlet's approximation theorem ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem)), but the absolute operator is 'in the way'. Or is such a limit impossible?

Comment: Not sure you got the question right ... I would say $\{p\alpha\}\leq\epsilon$ where $\alpha$ is a fixed real and $p$ very would make more sense. Otherwise, it is not clear what is the index $i$ for.

Comment: @Salcio Question is if there is a limit $\epsilon$ simultaneously valid for all different/arbitrary $\alpha_i$ and a single fixed $p$. The notation follows the Wikipedia text.

Comment: If $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ are irrational and $\alpha_1+\alpha_2$ is an integer, you are in trouble.

Comment: @fedja If $\{p\alpha_1\}=\epsilon_1$ then $\{p(1-\alpha_1)\}=1-\epsilon_1$. So maybe you can find a $p$ for which all $\{p\alpha_i\}$ are (arbitrary) close to $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @JeroenBoschma That would be a different interpretation of the question from the one I used. So, do I understand it right that you are asking whether *For every n, there exists $\varepsilon=\varepsilon(n)\in(0,1)$ such that for every $a_1,\dots,a_n$, there exists $p$ such that $\{pa_i\}<\varepsilon$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$*?

Comment: @fedja Yes, that's what I mean. One $p$ applied to every $\alpha_i$. From your earlier comment I seemed to understand that this is not possible, so I threw in another option what then would mean $\varepsilon(n)=\frac{1}{2}$. Layman (-person...) overhere...

Comment: If one fixes $\alpha_1, ...\alpha_k$, such that they are linear independent over $Q$ then the tuples $({n\alpha_1},..., {n\alpha_k})$ should be uniformly distributed in the unit cube $[0,1]^k$. In particular, for any $\epsilon >0$ one can find $n$ such that ${n\alpha_i} <\epsilon$. Check out "Uniformly distributed sequences" by Kuipers